# How do I automatically pass a value to my controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I'm working on a project that is a simulation of banking. I am trying to set up the withdraw but can't figure out how I automatically pass the account ID to the controller with the amount wanting to be withdrawn. I keep getting an error in which it's saying there is a null entry for amount, meaning they are taking amount as the id variable.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Withdraw([Bind(Include = "balance")] int id, decimal amount)
{

if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        bankAccount bankAccount = db.Accounts.Find(id);
        if (bankAccount == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        if (bankAccount.type)
        {
            bankAccount.withdraw(amount);
        }
        else
        {
            if (amount > bankAccount.balance)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Amount", "Checking accounts can't be overdraft.");
                return View(bankAccount);
            }
            else
            {
                bankAccount.withdraw(amount);
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(bankAccount).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = bankAccount.customerID });
        }
        return View(bankAccount);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model BankProject.bankAccount

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Withdraw";

}

<h2>Withdraw</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Withdraw", "bankAccounts", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>bankAccount</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.accountID)


    <div class="form-group">
        Remaining Balance: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.balance) <br />
            Withdraw amount: <input type="number" name="out" id="moneyW" />
            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Withdraw" />

    </div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Did you post the complete view (the first using is not closed)?

Comment: Updated it but there really wasnt much missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

Firstly, you're using not providing a hidden field for `balance`. All data sent to the server must have an associated `input` element that can be sent back by the browser. `Html.DisplayFor()` does not render an `input` element. `Html.EditorFor()` does, but is not appropriate if you don't want a user to edit the value in the UI. In this case, you must supply a hidden field.

Secondly, you are using `[Bind(Include = "balance")]` against the `id` parameter in your `Withdraw` action. This is going to stop you getting the correct value bound to `id`.

Finally, `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.accountID)` renders an input element whose name will be `accountID`. In order for values to be correctly bound together in your actions, they have to have the same name (or have correct prefixes for binding complex models). In your case, it means changing your action's signature to be:

```
Withdraw(int acccountID, decimal balance)
```

Doing that, along with adding `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.balance)` in your view, should resolve your issue.

At this point, if this works correctly for you, try changing the parameter in the action to `[Bind(Include = "balance")] decimal amount`, so you can get your desired parameter name of `amount`.

Comment: Firstly, thank you as your answer gave me some more insights about MVC, Secondly, i'm not trying to change the value of ID but the value in balance.after doing some calculations. I need id to make sure i edit the right account's balance.

Comment: @LaHenJ You're welcome. What does `ID` correspond with in your view? If it's not the account's ID, I don't see what else in your view you have that should map to it. Secondly, in your view, what are you expecting to be sent to the server as your `amount` parameter?

Comment: ID doesn't cosponsor to anything in this view. it's for controller use only. what I'm trying to map is a change in balance. I want the value from the input tag to be sent as amount, as it's the amount the user wishes to withdraw. My thought process was have mapping to balance as that's whats getting changed and to take in two parameters. The id of the account being changed and the amount you wish for that balance in that account to change by. If i change my action deceleration to `[Bind(Include = "balance")]` decimal amount' how do i get the id, or even find the account i want to change?

Comment: @LaHenJ This is what I was getting at above. You have to have some ID to relate to the action you're performing, and that means it has to be supplied by that form you're sending to the server, as there is no way to supply that ID otherwise. In your scenario, you need to withdraw an amount from a person's bank account, assuming they have enough funds to do so. That means you have to uniquely identify that bank account, which is why I feel you need to be passing `accountID` to your controller, along with the amount to withdraw. Whether the withdrawal can happen should be validated on the server.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but thanks again. You solved my issue.